# Cordova WP8 app sideloading

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

I have developed a Cordova app for WP8 platform and deployed it on the device through Visual Studio as well as using .xap file using Application Deployment Tool.

But if I copy the .xap file on the device and try to install by accessing the file via a file explorer app, it gives the message "Cannot install company app".

What is the correct procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> But if I copy the .xap file on the device and try to install by accessing the file via a file explorer app, it gives the message "Cannot install company app"

Indeed, there was some unofficial guidances about using this way to install .xap package on Windows phone before.

But based on this official document: [How to deploy and run an app for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx), the best way is using the Application Deployment tool or the command prompt. So we have no guarantee to ensure that way can work well now.